# Gradle error after importing from GitHub

Tags: java, android, github, android-studio, gradle

After importing a downloaded .zip project available on GitHub I got an error saying unable to find gradle. I had added the com.github... line into the build.gradle file as specified in the readme and that doesn't seemed to have worked either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you installed gradle?

Comment: yeah i installed the latest version just before importing

Comment: What does `gradle --version` say? If you cannot call `gradle` from the command-line you'll probably have to add the path to the gradle binary to you PATH variable

Comment: 2.3 i believe. I am currently at work so cant see my machine